# How to get url parameters in a class PHP

Tags: php, class, get, public

I bought a bunch of code to add Facebook events to the website I am creating. 
The overall goal is to have different pages for different venues. Each venue will have their own facebook page/events and I wish to show those events.

I have got everything down except for one little issue. I can grab data from the url parameters sent to the page with basic php (see below) but the class in the code will not allow me to do it.

```
$access_token= $_GET['access_token'];
$fb_page_id= $_GET['fb_page_id'];
// this works fine in a basic php file
```

I have been Googling for hours now and I cannot find a solution to this.

Below is what I thought would work when adding the same code but into a class.

```
class DsmFacebookEvents{

    public $access_token= $_GET['access_token'];
    public $fb_page_id= $_GET['fb_page_id'];
```

Please mind that I am not a professional with PHP and I thought that adding 'public' would fix the problem (as all the other variables in the class have this)

I get an error on the page saying...

```
Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$_GET' (T_VARIABLE) in (location)
```

If I call the variable with custom data (see below), it works fine. All I want to do is pull data from the url or from another php file. But I am unsure if I can ass this is all inside classes.

```
 public $access_token= "access_token_here";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could to move your runtime parameters into the constructor via two approaches. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

**Option A)**

```
class DsmFacebookEvents
{
  public $access_token;
  public $fb_page_id;
  public function __construct()
  {
    if( !empty( $_GET['access_token'] ) )
    {
      $this->access_token = $_GET['access_token'];
    }
    if( !empty( $_GET['fb_page_id'] ) )
    {
      $this->fb_page_id = $_GET['fb_page_id'];
    }
  }
}
```

**Option B)**

```
class DsmFacebookEvents
{
  public $access_token;
  public $fb_page_id;
  public function __construct( $access_token, $fb_page_id )
  {
    $this->access_token = $access_token;
    $this->fb_page_id = $fb_page_id;
  }
}

$foo = new DsmFacebookEvents( $_GET['access_token'], $_GET['fb_page_id'] );
```

The second option I feel is better since it disconnects the source of the values from the class definition. You can still choose to make them optional by modifying the constructor, or creating setter functions, or just leaving the parameters public.

`__construct()` is called every time you create an object instance of the class.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for you solutions. However, they both didn't work (but the last one may have hope).
First one doesn't seem to take any effect (i tried an isset solution similar to this but it didn't do anything)

The second one comes up with an error message saying that variables are undefined.

I then looked throughout the other php files linked to this one and found where DsmFacebookEvents is called.  I found out where my problem starts.

cont in next comment.

Comment: This other file is a basic php file and works like the first one that I got right. However, if I use
'''
$fb_page_id= $_GET['fb_page_id'];
$access_token= $_GET['access_token'];
'''
I get the same errors as I got in the class.

Thank you for your time mate. I really want to modify this code to work for me.
To run you down on what is going on. I got the first half of the code working. It will show me a list of events for each venue. But it will not show the details of the events. Right now we are working on the details of the events.

Apologizes if I am a bit complicated to understand.

Comment: `?access_token=whatever&fb_page_id=whatever` must be on the URL line of the current script, is this present on the page you're running? I can't see anything else beyond that sorry.